# How to convert Longitudinal data from wide to long format in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, tidyr, data-cleaning

Here is the basic information about my data, it is a Longitudinal dataset.
The variables are: ID, Age, Gender, Q1AnswerTime1, Q2AnswerTime1, Q3AnswerTime1, Q1AnswerTime2, Q2AnswerTime2, Q3AnswerTime2, Q1AnswerTime3, Q2AnswerTime3, Q3AnswerTime3.

Now, how can I transfer this dataset from wide format to longformat?
What I want is the long format only contains 7 variables: ID, Age, Gender, Q1Answer, Q2Answer, Q3Answer, and Time.
The values of Q1Answer, Q2Answer, and Q3Answer will depend on "Time" variable.

To be clear, for the original study, we have 5 people in this Longitudinal study, the study collected data for 3 years.
Every year, each person will be asked 3 questions: Q1, Q2, Q3.
So in the end, we have 12 variables in wide format.

Update the code part:

```
df <- tibble(
  ID = c(1, 2, 3),
  Age = c(25, 32, 28),
  Gender = c("Male", "Female", "Male"),
  Q1AnswerTime1 = c(10, 15, 12),
  Q2AnswerTime1 = c(7, 9, 8),
  Q3AnswerTime1 = c(5, 6, 4),
  Q1AnswerTime2 = c(11, 16, 13),
  Q2AnswerTime2 = c(8, 10, 9),
  Q3AnswerTime2 = c(6, 7, 5),
  Q1AnswerTime3 = c(12, 17, 14),
  Q2AnswerTime3 = c(9, 11, 10),
  Q3AnswerTime3 = c(7, 8, 6)
)

df
```

And the expected output will be like this:

```
dfLong <- tibble(
  ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2, 3,3,3),
  Age = c(25,25,25,32,32, 32, 28,28,28),
  Gender = c("Male","Male","Male", "Female","Female","Female", "Male","Male","Male"),
  Q1 = c(10,11,12,15,16,17,12,13,14),
  Q2 = c(7,8,9,9,10,11,8,9,10),
  Q3 = c(5,6,7,6,7,8,4,5,6),
  Time = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
)
```

I try to use tidyr function in R but this example is too complex for me, can you guys help me with that?

Thanks!
[OriginalDataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6qTb.png)

[ExpectedOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK5M2.png)

Comment: Instead of describing the data, give a sample. ie data with 3-4 rows that represent your true data

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Here’s a link which may be useful to asking a question that makes it easier for others to help. [Link for guidance on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)